# How to export inter-depended Node.js functions efficiently

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js module containing numerous functions:

`myfuncs.js`:

```
var foo = function(d) { return d + 1 })
var bar = function(d) { return foo(d) + 2 }
var baz = function(d) { return foo(d) + bar(d) + 3 })
```

I'd like to export all of these function in `myfuncs.js` for use in another module. What is the best way to accomplish this? Since some of the functions are used in other functions; for example `foo` is used in `bar` and `baz`, the only way I can see to export, is to list all the exports like this, so that they are available in another module.

`myfuncs.js`:

```
var foo = function(d) { return d + 1 })
var bar = function(d) { return foo(d) + 2 }
var baz = function(d) { return foo(d) + bar(d) + 3 })

module.exports.foo = foo;
module.exports.bar = bar;
module.exports.baz = baz;
```

My issue is that I have dozens of functions and exporting each function in this manner seems inefficient. Is there a better way to export Node functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the functions you want to export will have to be added to the exports object (or to some other object) individually.  There is no way around that.

But, there are sometimes simpler ways to declare your functions such that the declaration already makes them properties on an object that you can directly export.

For example, you could just declare them like this:

```
var exportedFuncs = {
    foo: function() {...}, 
    bar: function() {...}, 
    baz: function() {...}
};

module.exports = exportedFuncs;
```

When doing it this way, if `bar` called `foo`, then you'd either have to call it as `exportedFuncs.foo()` or create a local alias for it.

---

What I've seen a lot as a common method of handling this is a combination of your original scheme and the above scheme where you declare all the functions individually like you are doing:

```
var foo = function(d) { return d + 1 }
var bar = function(d) { return foo(d) + 2 }
var baz = function(d) { return foo(d) + bar(d) + 3 }
```

And, then you declare an exports object for just the functions you want to export:

```
module.exports = {
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar,
    baz: baz
};
```

In ES6, this last declaration can be shortened quite a bit with some [new ES6 object initializer syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to:

```
module.exports = {foo, bar, baz};
```

---

Another variation of what you are already doing is this:

```
var foo = module.exports.foo = function(d) { return d + 1 }
var bar = module.exports.bar = function(d) { return foo(d) + 2 }
var baz = module.exports.baz = function(d) { return foo(d) + bar(d) + 3 }
```

Comment: You can even do:
exports.foo = foo =function() {};
exports.bar = bar =function() {};
exports.baz = baz =function() {};

Comment: @YlinaGreed - thx.  I added a variation of that to my answer.